# Cant collapse block

Tags: 7

My mentor gave me a assignment I have to create a block  the users last login with the timezone. I did that  on this site http://dev-bor.pantheon.io. My issue is that the assignment said that i need to collapse the block with javascript every 10 seconds. So I used the API of the collapsible block module , installed fine but I can't get it to collapse. I am a noob. My code will be below.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Install, update and uninstall functions for the block_example module.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 *
 * @ingroup block_example
 */



function block_example_collapsiblock_init() {
    //load the settings
    global $theme;
    $current_theme = $theme ? $theme : variable_get('theme_default', 'garland');
    $collapsiblock_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'collapsiblock');
    $theme_settings = variable_get(str_replace('/', '_', 'theme_' . $current_theme . '_settings'), array());
    $theme_settings = array_merge(collapsiblock_default_settings(), $theme_settings, array());
    drupal_add_js(array(
        'collapsiblock' => array(
            'blocks' => variable_get('collapsiblock_settings', array()),
            'default_state' => variable_get('collapsiblock_default_state', 1),
            'slide_type' => variable_get('collapsiblock_slide_type', 1),
            'slide_speed' => variable_get('collapsiblock_slide_speed', 10),
            'block_title' => $theme_settings['collapsiblock_title'],
            'block' => $theme_settings['collapsiblock_block'],
            'block_content' => $theme_settings['collapsiblock_content'],
            )), array('type' => 'setting'
        , 'scope' => JS_DEFAULT));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function block_example_collapsiblock_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/user-interface/collapsiblock'] = array(
    'title' => 'Collapsiblock',
    'description' => 'Configuration for collapsible blocks',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('collapsiblock_admin_settings'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Admin settings.
 */
function block_example_collapsiblock_admin_settings($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $form['block_example_collapsiblock_default_state'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Default block collapse behavior'),
    '#options' => array(1 => t('None.'), 2 => t('Collapsible, expanded by default.'), 3 => t('Collapsible, collapsed by default.'), 4 => t('Collapsible, collapsed all the time.')),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('block_example_collapsiblock_default_state', 1),
  );
  $form['block_example_collapsiblock_slide_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Default animation type'),
    '#options' => array(1 => t('Slide'), 2 => t('Fade and slide')),
    '#description' => t('Slide is the Drupal default while Fade and slide adds a nice fade effect.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('block_example_collapsiblock_slide_type', 1),
  );
  $form['block_example_collapsiblock_slide_speed'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Animation speed'),
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('10000')),
    '#description' => t('The animation speed in milliseconds.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('block_example_collapsiblock_slide_speed', 10000),
  );
  $form['block_example_collapsiblock_help'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('If collapsiblock doesn\'t work out of the box, you can force CSS selectors on <a href="!url">appearance settings</a>.', array('!url' => url('admin/appearance/settings'))),
  );

function block_example_uninstall() {
  variable_del('block_example_string');
}
```